# Auto place grid items within named column?

Tags: css

I have a simple 4 column grid where I want most of the content to fall within the named column area in the middle.

Is it possible to adjust the column span of a grid item so that they take 1fr and line up in a row, but still only within the central area?

- I would like to do this without adding additional wraps
- There are items not shown here that make use of the wider parts of the grid.
- There is a variable amount of items that may or may not have the 'small' class, and should remain in order.

HTML

```
<div class="grid">
  <p>Item</p>
  <p class="small">Item</p>
  <p class="small">Item</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.grid {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:
    [grid-start] 1fr
    [content-start] 1fr 1fr [content-end]
    1fr [grid-end]
  ;
}

.grid p {
  grid-column:content;
}

.grid .small {
  grid-column:content / span 1;
}
```

So the grid would look something like this:
[image: Example of desired grid layout]

Comment: What does it mean to "line up in a row, but still only within the central area"? Do you mean if there are two small items consecutively, they should be in the same row?

Comment: @SyndRain Yes, thats right.

Comment: will you have content outside the content area or not? because if it's not the case you should rely on margin/padding to create space

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `:nth-child()` selector to place the items at the 2nd or 3rd column.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr);
  gap: 5px;
  grid-auto-flow: dense; /* don't leave empty columns */
}

.grid p {
  grid-column: 2 / span 2; /* by default at column 2 and taking 2 columns */
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
/* the odd items at second column */
.grid p:nth-child(odd  of .small) {
  grid-column: 2;
}
/* the even items at the third column */
.grid p:nth-child(even of .small) {
  grid-column: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <p>Item</p>
  <p class="small">Item</p>
  <p class="small">Item</p>
  <p class="small">Item</p>
  <p class="small">Item</p>
  <p>Item</p>
  <p class="small">Item</p>
  <p class="small">Item</p>
  <p>Item</p>
  <p class="small">Item</p>
  <p>Item</p>
  <p class="small">Item</p>
</div>
```

And if you won't have content outside the middle area, use padding:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2,1fr);
  padding-inline: 25%;
  gap: 5px;
  grid-auto-flow: dense; /* don't leave empty columns */
}

.grid p {
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
.grid p:not(.small) {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <p>Item</p>
  <p class="small">Item</p>
  <p class="small">Item</p>
  <p class="small">Item</p>
  <p class="small">Item</p>
  <p>Item</p>
  <p class="small">Item</p>
  <p class="small">Item</p>
  <p>Item</p>
  <p class="small">Item</p>
  <p>Item</p>
  <p class="small">Item</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The items are variable and could be in any order, so `nth-child` would not work. And yes, there are other items not specified here that are outside the content area.

Comment: @user500665 check well the syntax of nth-child() I am using. The order doesn't matter because I am only counting the small items so they will get placed correctly (as you can see in the first demo)

Comment: Unfortunately, nth(of) will not work if there are an odd number of small items. The dense grid arrangement is not useable because I need them to remain in order.